# Concurrency with STM in Clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure, parallel-processing, functional-programming, stm

I am currently learning Clojure and I am unsure of how to use the STM to do concurrency. The task I am trying to accomplish is very simple, I have a vector of strings, I want to run a function on each of the strings concurrently, and replace the string with what the function returns.

I can currently do this very easily with pmap:

```
(pmap function string_vector)
```

How can I do this same thing using the STM in Clojure?

Comment: I have voted to close this. The problem is not well posed because it has no requirements in the space of thread coordination that would lead to STM as a problem related piece of the solution. Its like asking how can I eat apples using a dishwasher?

Answer (score 2):

STM is a way of sharing data across threads. If you don't need to coordinate at all (which you don't in this example), there's no real reason to use STM.

Comment: I understand. I just want to know for learning purposes. I'm having a hard time understanding STM, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Pythoner, just because it is for "learning purposes" doesn't mean it shouldn't make sense.  What you are asking is like saying "I have an airplane.  How can I use it to learn to drive (a car)?"  Sure, you could taxi your airplane along the highway.  But you would be none the wiser about actually driving a car -- they are entirely different machines, with very different intended uses, and are controlled differently.

Answer (score 1):

The STM in clojure is about maintaining the state of mutable things over time. These things that have a state that changes from moment to moment are said to have "an identity". Just as you have an identity that is "you" for your whole life, even if "you" at three months old may not recognise "you" at 120 years old. So lets put something mutable in your example so we have an excuse to use the STM:

Let's make a publicly available mutable place to store the strings and then change them there in parallel:

```
user> (def current-strings (ref ["a" "b" "c"]))
#'user/current-strings
user> (dosync (alter current-strings (fn [the-string-at-this-instant]
                                       (pmap #(.toUpperCase %) the-string-at-this-instant))))
("A" "B" "C")
user> @current-strings
("A" "B" "C")
user>
```

In this example we created a transaction that changed the state of our collection of strings by applying a function to it. Internally that function happened to compute the new values in parallel.

to make this more interesting let's make a vector of mutable things, and then in a parallel update a bunch of independently mutable things each in it's own transaction:

```
user> (def current-strings [(ref "a") (ref "b") (ref "c")])
#'user/current-strings

user> (doall
       (pmap (fn [ref-to-update]
               (dosync (alter ref-to-update #(.toUpperCase %))))
             current-strings))
("A" "B" "C")

user> (map deref current-strings)
("A" "B" "C")
user>
```

As you can see, none of this needs the STM, because all these operations can be handled with the other mutable types in clojure, atoms would be a great choice. And playing with refs is fun too! Have fun!

Comment: Be careful here. Since pmap is, like map, lazy, you should not merely evaluate it for side effects, but force the whole thing if you want to be sure all the results are realized. If you didn't happen to print this in the repl, none of those changes would be guaranteed to occur (and in fact only the first 32 would, because of chunking). Note the repeated 32 in https://gist.github.com/amalloy/906a65d5851ab61554b12482a8dbcb4a.

Comment: good point! the "lazy bug" is lurking around here. I put a `doall` in there. It's also worth noting that if you put the dosync outside the pmap it does not work.

Comment: That doall doesn't make sense. You're calling doall on a string, which is a no-op. Again, try it on something with more than 32 elements without printing the result to the repl to see if it's right. You need to doall the result of pmap, not anything inside it.

Comment: I totally slapped that In without actually testing the example, I'll fix it properly now. Thanks for keeping me honest.